# Why isn't "Read More" button working in Div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a website using divi and I manually added a READ MORE button which doesn't work. Please help!

I was using a complex code, I narrowed it down to match exactly w3school's and it still doesn't work.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; 
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; 
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
```

```css
#more {display: none;}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<h3><em>Let me tell you a Story!!!!!</em></h3>
<p style="text-align: left;">Let us imagine a boy. A brilliant, hardworking and dedicated chap. Always thinking about how he is going to study everything, what more he’s going to learn today and how one day he’s going to change the world. Everyone got inspired when they see this gentleman. One day a person finds out that this extraordinary lad is deciding to leave <span id="dots">...</span><span id="more">
the college, just like a sapling deciding to quit sunlight. He was appalled at the possibility that the world will never see that immense potential realized. He digs deeper and discovers the most unfortunate situation. The boy’s father was an addict, his brothers were hardly supportive and he was barely able to pay his fee till now. And now the support was gone. He couldn’t pay the pence that kept the ball rolling and the wheels of the train to his future turning. Imagine being denied of oxygen of wisdom for your lungs, glucose of rationality for your brain and choir of knowledge in your veins.
<br>
Now imagine as 22 million children in our country are&nbsp; denied even primary education. The person wanted to help him but he couldn’t possibly pay that much money. He took the name of Allah and started asking for donations. He believed in the humankind and its potential for good. It wasn’t easy at first but soon enough he could see the power of drops becoming waves and waves becoming an ocean. He witnessed the power of collective good, the emergence of something greater than the constituents. He was humbled by the grace of God that day. The boy’s fee was paid but the<br>burning flame of service still remained.
<br>
<em><strong>That flame was the birth of Muaawin and that person was I, Muhammad Shaheer Farooq and the boy became a friend, not to mention a top student.</strong></em></p>
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read more</button>
```

Comment: I pasted the exact code of yours in w3 school's online editor and it works for me.... You have missed the `</span>` for `<span id="more">` but this wont create any issue in modern browsers...

Comment: do you get any error in browser console? Also, you are missing `<span>` closing tag. There should be `</span>` before `</p>`

Comment: I did that, and the read more button still appears at the end of the entire text.

Comment: "Doesn't work" sounds strange as the given snipped provides a working preview

Comment: I mean to say that it doesn't work the way it should. The read more button appears at the end of the entire text.

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/pZHh9il) It looks like this

Answer (score -1):

Your inserted code works fine.

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
#more {display: none;}
</style>


<h3><em>Let me tell you a Story!!!!!</em></h3>
<p style="text-align: left;">Let us imagine a boy. A brilliant, hardworking and dedicated chap. Always thinking about how he is going to study everything, what more he’s going to learn today and how one day he’s going to change the world. Everyone got inspired when they see this gentleman. One day a person finds out that this extraordinary lad is deciding to leave <span id="dots">...</span><span id="more">
the college, just like a sapling deciding to quit sunlight. He was appalled at the possibility that the world will never see that immense potential realized. He digs deeper and discovers the most unfortunate situation. The boy’s father was an addict, his brothers were hardly supportive and he was barely able to pay his fee till now. And now the support was gone. He couldn’t pay the pence that kept the ball rolling and the wheels of the train to his future turning. Imagine being denied of oxygen of wisdom for your lungs, glucose of rationality for your brain and choir of knowledge in your veins.
<br>
Now imagine as 22 million children in our country are&nbsp; denied even primary education. The person wanted to help him but he couldn’t possibly pay that much money. He took the name of Allah and started asking for donations. He believed in the humankind and its potential for good. It wasn’t easy at first but soon enough he could see the power of drops becoming waves and waves becoming an ocean. He witnessed the power of collective good, the emergence of something greater than the constituents. He was humbled by the grace of God that day. The boy’s fee was paid but the<br>burning flame of service still remained.
<br>
<em><strong>That flame was the birth of Muaawin and that person was I, Muhammad Shaheer Farooq and the boy became a friend, not to mention a top student.</strong></em></p>
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="myBtn">Read more</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read more"; 
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Read less"; 
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It works fine in that editor, but on wordpress, the read more button appears after the text. I've been trying different codes for an hour now :(

Comment: You mean it appears after the text horizontally? If yes than it could be a layout issue. ->CSS